# Is it possible to use same imagePullSecret across cluster once created?

Tags: openshift

I have created imagePullSecret in Openshift 4.3 cluster namespace. To use it in another namespace I have to again create it that namespace too. Is there a way to create a secret once and use it in all namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO !! Secret are API objects in a namespace scope. They can only be use by pods,deployments or replicasets within same namespace. In nutshell , you have to create the secret for every namespace. and this is same for configMaps.

Here is the link for more info

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-imagepullsecrets

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#details